# Force magic constant

Tags: java, android

I'm making a few classes which I intent to hopefully put out as a library once done. In it I use Magic Constants (I believe that's the correct term)

```
public static final int LIST = 0;
public static final int GRID = 1;
```

Is it possible in Java/Android to force when a method `setMode(int mode)` is called, they must use either `LIST` or `GRID`? So if they pass `0`, `1`, `15`, `999` etc into the function it throws an error/warning? Or can Java not tell the difference between `LIST` and `0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Enum. See the example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html In your case I would suggest:

```
public enum Mode { LIST, GRID }

setMode(Mode mode);
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, I'd heard of enum but never used it before. Is this the way Android defines things like `Gravivty.TOP`?

Comment: No, these are special constants used for defining multiple things inside one integer ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array )

Comment: Oh, does either emun or Bit array have any advantage over the other?

Comment: Yes there are differences. One thing that comes to my mind: although `enum` is similar to a class, you *can not* extend it. On the other hand `enum` grants type safety. I guess android SDK almost always uses `int` for that type of constants *because* enum is not extendable. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: These are tools for different things. Enums give you an ability to enumerate a set of elements (options). When some kind of Enum is expected, compiler will force you to provide the right kind: "Mode" in this case. Bit field http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field on the other hand can store more information at the same time.